# MongoDB Mongoose: Get data from two collection in one call

Tags: mongodb

So I have a collection for saving articles in, one of the keys in this collection is the `userId` where I save the _id from the user's collection.

```
const articleSchema: Schema = new Schema(
  {
    body: { type: String },
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    subTitle: { type: String, required: true },
    userId: { type: Number, required: true, index: true },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

When I get one of the articles, I also want to get the User's name and other information stored in the user's collection.

```
const userSchema: Schema = new Schema(
  {
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true, index: true },
    country: { type: String },
    fullName: { type: String, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

Do I have to make 2 calls to the database or is there some way of making just one? Something like a join in SQL

```
const account = await articleSchema // <-----can I also select the userSchema?
        .findOne(
          { userId }
        )
        .exec();
```

I want to get the article and the user details who wrote the article in one call if possible

Answer (score 0):

You can look into this [Lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

Performs a left outer join to an unsharded collection in the same database to filter in documents from the “joined” collection for processing

```
{
 $lookup:
 {
   from: <collection to join>,
   localField: <field from the input documents>,
   foreignField: <field from the documents of the "from" collection>,
   as: <output array field>
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put reference in your Article Schema so you can change userId to below in your Article Schema:

```
userId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'userSchema', // put user schema here
    required: true
}
```

and write query like this:

```
const account = await articleSchema
    .findOne(
      { userId: userId_value_here }
    ).populate('userId', 'email fullName')
```

it will gives you Article Object with User object in userId key
the output will be like below:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5dca81898cc8cc03a4a759b0"),
"__v" : 0,
"body" : "body",
"title" : "title",
"subTitle": "sub title",
"userId": {
              "_id" : ObjectId("5dca81898cc8cc03d56s6ada"),
              "email": "email@email.com",
              "fullName" : "name"
          }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using lookup, It will return the user's details from user collection.

```
  db.collection('articles').aggregate([{$lookup:{from:"users",localField:"userId",foreignField:"_id", as:"userDetails"}}])
```